# Unit testing for component with private @ViewChild child component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

How to write Unit testing for component with private @ViewChild child component?

Note: I can't change or update the main component codes just for writing test case.

Main component Code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="update()">Update</button>
    <br>
    <app-child></app-child>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: false })
  private childComponent!: ChildComponent;
    
  flag=false;
  update() {
        this.childComponent.updateTimeStamp();
        this.flag=true;
      }
}
```

Unit test code:
Issue is when I try to supply mock object for app.childComponent in below code. Though it works if I add // @ts-ignore but I don't think its correct. There must be a way to mock private ViewChild component.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  
  it('should call update', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.flag).toBe(false);
   **// app.update(); //fails**
  });
```

if it would have been non-private member, I could mock the child component like this.

```
  it('should call update', () => {
     const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
     const app = fixture.componentInstance;
     app.childComponent = <ChildComponent>{updateTimeStamp:()=>{}}
     expect(app.flag).toBe(false);
     app.update(); 
     expect(app.flag).toBe(true);
   });


});
```

Comment: And what would you like to test? But in general, the same way you would test anything else.

Comment: This is the best article on how to test `ViewChild`: https://indepth.dev/posts/1184/angular-unit-testing-viewchild.

Comment: @AliF50 I went through this article already. Didn't help much for private member case as I can't directly access component.childComponent .

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes. Edited question and tried to explain it better.

Comment: You can always do this: `(component as any).childComponent` to access it.

Comment: yeah just did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
 it('should call update', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const app = fixture.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
        (app as any).childComponent = <ChildComponent>{updateTimeStamp:()=>{}}
        app.update()
        expect(app.flag).toBe(true)
        
      });
```

Please comment if you've got any other better approach.

Thanks @AliF50